# is it something obvious that console.log('true text' || true ? 'text' : 'text1'); logs 'text'?

Tags: javascript

I though it should have printed 'true text' given it's equivalent of true

```
console.log('true text' || true ? 'text' : 'text1');
```

But instead, the output is 'text';
Sorry if's stupid...

Comment: Take a look at [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Comment: yeah, thanks, I guess it's obvious, but maybe a bit tricky

Comment: So if 'true text' OR true is true then you put out 'text', so if true always brings you true i dont get your question

Comment: I guess you were expecting `'true text' || (true ? 'text' : 'text1')`, but what you get is `('true text' || true) ? 'text' : 'text1'`.

Comment: yeah, I get it now, thanks and sorry for the stupid question... rookie mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) syntax. 
You are doing something like this:

```
if ('true text' || true)
    console.log('text');
else
    console.log('text1');
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out!
I ended up doing like this: 
'true text' ? 'true text' : true ? 'text' : 'text1'

Answer (score 1):

Here 'true text' is OR ed with true and the result will be always true. Hence the value getting print will be 'text'

Comment: "_the result will be always true_" From `||`? Nope, the result will always be "true text"-

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of ternary opeartor is

```
Condition ? <Return if condition is true> : <Return if condition is false> ;
```

In your case you are using true with or operator so it will return `text1` always

**(true || any condition) will return true *always***

Answer (score 0):

console.log('true text' || true ? 'text' : 'text1');

In the above statement, `'true text' || true ?` expression always evaluates to `True` (because you have `|| true` expression) hence you will get 'text' string.